# Changing the color of <option> in firefox

Tags: jquery, css, firefox

I'm trying to change the text color of the option that is selected. It's working in IE but not in Firefox.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){
            $("option:selected").css("color", "green");
         });
      </script>
</head>
<body>
   <select id="mySelect">
      <option selected="selected">option 1</option>
      <option>option 2</option>
      <option>option 3</option>
   </select>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATED**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
   <head>
         <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){
            $("select").css("color", "green").focus(function() {
                    $(this).css('color', 'black');
                }).blur(function() {
                $(this).css('color', 'green');
            });
         });
      </script>
</head>
<body>
   <select id="mySelect">
      <option selected="selected">option 1</option>
      <option>option 2</option>
      <option>option 3</option>
   </select>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATED 2**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
   <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            select.green{
              color: green;
            }
            option {
              color: black;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var green = $('option:selected', 'select').data('green');
                if (green) {
                    $('select').addClass('green');
                }
                $('select').change(function() {
                    var green = $('option:selected', this).data('green');
                    if (green) {
                        $('select').addClass('green');
                    }
                    else {
                        $('select').removeClass('green');
                    }
                });​
             });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="mySelect">
            <option selected="selected" data-green="true">option 1</option>
            <option>option 2</option>
            <option>option 3</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want the red color for the selected option only when the DOM has loaded. So, the above code should be fine but it's not working in FF.

Comment: I made a demo for you.  http://jsfiddle.net/R8aPY/  In Chrome and Firefox, option 1 is green when you open the drop down.

Comment: You mean green color? Please be aware that after the user changes his selection it will not update the colour to the newly selected element.

Comment: @Rocket: option 1 is not green. Option 1 is green only when I open the select box and move my cursor from option 1 to option 2 or option 3.

Comment: @SK11: Yes, that's what I said.  What do you want it to do?  Pretty sure you can't change the color of the element when the cursor is over it.

Comment: @Rocket: Please read the my first comment -- `I want the green color for the selected option only when the DOM has loaded. So, the above code should be fine but it's not working in FF.`

Comment: @SK11: I see no "red color" in your code.  When the DOM loads, it makes the selected option green.  You can see it when you open the drop down and move the cursor.  Do you want the drop down to be green when it's closed?  When it's open and the cursor is over it?

Comment: @Rocket: I want option 1 to be in green color WHEN THE PAGE LOADS and NOT when you open the drop down and move the cursor.

Comment: @SK11: Read my edited answer. I think I know what you're trying to do now.

Comment: @SK11: Ok.  In that case, just style the `select` itself, not the option.  When you open it, remove the color, and add it back when closed.

Comment: @Rocket: how do I write code for opening a select box?

Comment: @SK11: Check my answer.  The `onfocus` event *may* work.

Comment: @SK11: So, you want the select (but not the options) to be green when 'option 1' is selected, but not then when the other options are selected?

Comment: @Rocket: yes, option 1 should be green WHEN the page loads AND when it is selected. Other options should not be green at any time.

Comment: Firefox seems to have an old bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=910022 which limits the styling  of`option` elements.  I have Firefox 68.10.0esr, and it's not fixed yet.

Answer (score 6):

This might not be the solution you are looking for but you can do that in css:

```
option[selected] {
    color: green;
}
```

This only works with browsers that support attribute selectors (IE7+)

EDIT:
After reading your comment I understand what you want to achieve. You want to make the `select` green AND the selected element (`option`) green (and the rest to black). You can do this by using the following css code:

```
select {
  color: green;
}

option[selected] {
  color: green;
}

option {
  color: black;
}
```

​See my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R8aPY/8/). However the colours won't change after you select a different option.

Comment: No it doesn't in Firefox... all options elements are black on white when the ddl is open, always.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here:

http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-misc/examples/selectcolorize/

> By default, select elements in Internet Explorer and Opera show the
>   selected option's color and background color, while Firefox and WebKit
>   browsers do not. jQuery selectColorize normalizes this behavior
>   cross-browser for basic select box color styling, without having to
>   resort to more "fancy" select box replacements.

Comment: I don't want the color of option 1 to be set to green on `change` event. Please re-read the question/comments. I want option 1 to be green when the page loads.

Comment: all elements in the list are monochrome in firefox 52.0.2 (64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

So, you want the select to be green when "option 1" is selected, but not when the others are?

I suggest adding an attribute to "option 1", so you know that's one that should be green, and then toggle a class on the select when it's changed.

So, change your HTML to be this:

```
<select id="mySelect">
   <option selected="selected" data-green="true">option 1</option>
   <option>option 2</option>
   <option>option 3</option>
</select>​​​
```

Add this to your CSS:

```
select.green{
  color: green;
}
option {
  color: black;
}​
```

And try this JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
    var green = $('option:selected', 'select').data('green');
    if (green) {
        $('select').addClass('green');
    }


    $('select').change(function() {
        var green = $('option:selected', this).data('green');
        if (green) {
            $('select').addClass('green');
        }
        else {
            $('select').removeClass('green');
        }
    });​
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/UyxaT/3/

Comment: Please see updated code under `UPDATED 2`. Even though the demo works, I tried it in FF 9.0.1 and IE 8. It's not working in any browser.

Comment: @SK11: Works for me in Chrome 18, FF 10.  Doesn't seem to work in IE 9.  Styling `<select>` elements, doesn't seem to work in IE.